# Не могу загрузить png в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, png, corel-draw

Рисовал картинки в Corel, импортировал в PNG формат, добавляю в студию через Asset Studio, а он мне выдает это:
[image: Configure image asset]

Гугл ничего толком не дал. PNG скачанное с нета загружает нормально (появляются рисунки при загрузке). Видимо дело в экспорте с Corel в PNG.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Там все просто. Имя файла у вас с пробелами, а студия видать не понимает таких названий, и схватывает только первую часть названия до первого пробела, а дальше подставляет расширение png. Потому и вылезает ошибка, что файл не найден.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы рисовали в Corel'e, то скорее всего в векторе. Так зачем юзать раст? Экспортируйте в svg, и его используйте в студии